# OpenSSL - Raspberry Pi4 failing to communicate to server on windows system

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, raspberry-pi, openssl

As the title states I get an error trying to communicate from a Raspberry PI 4 and windows system using an SSL connection.

The current client script works perfectly on windows to a server application running on windows.

This is the client script:

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
import sys, os, select, socket, time

ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)

sock = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))

sock.connect(('10.0.0.84', 443))

stri = 'hello\r\n'
tobyte = bytes(stri,'utf-8')
print(tobyte)

buf = sock.recv(4096)

while True:
    sock.send(tobyte)
    time.sleep(60)
```

The error I get on Raspberry Pi 4:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/pi/Documents/scripts/openssltest.py", line 15, in 
> buf = sock.recv(4096)
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1791, in recv
> self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1647, in
> _raise_ssl_error
> _raise_current_error()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 54, in
> exception_from_error_queue
> raise exception_type(errors) OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl_choose_client_version', 'unsupported protocol')]

I have the same version of OpenSSL running on the Raspberry Pi and Windows PC

One thing I noticed in Visual Studio Code (for the Raspberry Pi) is that the sock.send() is not recognised but sock.sendall() is. VSC in windows is showing sock.send() as an option.

I am using OpenSSL version 1.1.1k and python 3.7.3 on the Raspberry PI. OpenSSL 1.1.1k and python 3.9.6 on windows. All devices are running on the same network

I have not written the server application but uses a self signed certificate.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: What is the server on the Windows side? Is it also your Python code, or is it something else?

Comment: It is a server application written in Delphi using OpenSSL aswell. Simply listens on port 443 and shows messages sent to it. This application was written by another employee.

Comment: `('SSL routines', 'ssl_choose_client_version', 'unsupported protocol')` usually means the server will only allow connections using certain SSL/TLS protocols (e.g. TLS1.2 or above), but the client does not support any of the protocols that the server requires (e.g. client supports TLS1.0 or lower).  Can you try connecting to the server from the command line of the PI, by doing `openssl s_client -connect 10.0.0.84:443`?  Does it connect?  If so, what protocol does it use?

Comment: On the Raspberry Pi, It connects to the server using that command. Under SSL-Session it says, Protocol: TLSv1. how do I go about allowing support for TLSv1? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the output in the terminal:
New, SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA

Comment: Thank you @mti2935 your comment solved my problem. Changed the SSL.SSLv23_METHOD to SSL.TLSv1_METHOD. Seems the windows PC works for both SSL.SSLv23 and SSL.TLSv1_METHOD

Answer (score 0):

Adding @mti2935 comment as the answer as this fixed my problem. Just to help anyone in the future

> ('SSL routines', 'ssl_choose_client_version', 'unsupported protocol')
> usually means the server will only allow connections using certain
> SSL/TLS protocols (e.g. TLS1.2 or above), but the client does not
> support any of the protocols that the server requires (e.g. client
> supports TLS1.0 or lower). Can you try connecting to the server from
> the command line of the PI, by doing openssl s_client -connect
> 10.0.0.84:443? Does it connect? If so, what protocol does it use?

The problem was that my client was using a protocol that the server did not support SSLv23_METHOD. Changed the protocol to SSL.TLSv1_METHOD.

Corrected code:

```
from OpenSSL import SSL

import sys, os, select, socket, time

ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.TLSv1_METHOD)

sock = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM))

sock.connect(('10.0.0.84', 443))

stri = 'hello\r\n'
tobyte = bytes(stri,'utf-8')
print(tobyte)

buf = sock.recv(4096)
print(buf)
while True:
        sock.send(tobyte)
        time.sleep(5)
```